# How do I get weblogic to pick up login module jaas.config from inside ear file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

We have a custom login module (well actually several) for our application.  We have recently moved to Weblogic from OC4J where we used to configure this in system-jazn-data.xml.

We have got our authentication to work correctly, however, to use the JAAS module, we are having to configure a java startup parameter pointing to a jaas.config file:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.config
```

File contents:

```
DatabaseAuthentication {
  uk.co.corelogic.framework.security.auth.module.RDBMSLoginModule optional debug=false;
};
```

My question is, is there another way to do this?

The problem is, I am trying to remove any external dependencies from the application ear, so that it can be deployed with default configuration without having to create files on the application sever.

I have looked all over the place, but all the instructions I have found say to specify an external file.  It's an awfully simple bit of config - can it be put into the deployment descriptor files anywhere?

There are other things I need to change too, but they warrant separate questions :)

Comment: Without fail, I've seen ~a half hour wasted every time someone sets up a new dev environment because they forgot to put the login module in the special place. Bundling it up like you describe would save tons of time and hassle.

Comment: What "special place" ?

Comment: @Chris: I am struggling with customized JAAS setup with WebLogic 12c. Can you pelase help with the steup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I spent some time looking at this and I think I have a decent solution. Instead of using  the `login.conf` file and the `-Dsecurity.auth.login..` junk, you can make a configuration class that contains the necessary information and pass that in when you create your `LoginContext`. Here's a simple example of the class I made:

```
public class MyAppLoginModuleConfig extends javax.security.auth.login.Configuration {
    private static final String APP_NAME = "MyApp";
    private static final String LOGIN_MODULE_CLASS = "com.myapp.security.MyLoginModule";

    @Override
    public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
        if (name.equals(APP_NAME)) {
            AppConfigurationEntry[] configArr = new AppConfigurationEntry[1];

            configArr[0] = new AppConfigurationEntry(
                LOGIN_MODULE_CLASS,
                AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUISITE, // or required, sufficient, etc
                new HashMap<String, Object>()); // for any options you have, can't be null
            return configArr;
        }
        // something funky happened and we're trying to look up a different app
        throw new RuntimeException("Expected app: " + APP_NAME + ", but got: " + name);
    }
}
```

And when you create your login context pass it in like so:

```
Subject subject = null;
Configuration myAppConfig = new MyAppLoginModuleConfig();
LoginContext ctx = new LoginContext("MyApp", subject, callbackHandler, myAppConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I missed your reply all that time ago, but it looks to be a good answer.  We could easily adapt this to our needs, so I have given you the points now.